# How can I generate Flash HTML wrappers in a WAR using Flexmojos and Maven 3?

Tags: maven, maven-3, flexmojos, maven-war-plugin

I have two Maven projects: one to build a SWF and another one to build a WAR that contains it. The WAR needs to contain a Flash wrapper for the SWF. Flexmojos is apparently capable of doing this via the [HTML wrapper mojo](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Html+Wrapper+Mojo), but this doesn't work with Maven 3. See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/flex-mojos@googlegroups.com/msg09453.html) for more details.

Is there a workaround for this?

My SWF POM has the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1-beta</version>
    <configuration>
        <parameters>
            <swf>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</swf>
            <title>My application title</title>
            <width>100%</width>
            <height>100%</height>
            <bgcolor>#ffffff</bgcolor>
        </parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and my WAR POM has the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1-beta</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wrapper</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wrapper</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wrapperArtifact>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>the-swc-project</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </wrapperArtifact>
                <htmlName>index</htmlName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-flex-resources</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I discovered that the problem here is that Flexmojos tries to reconfigure the WAR plugin, but it does so in a way that doesn't work with Maven 3.

The fairly grim workaround that I found involved manually configuring the WAR plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceExcludes>index.template.html</warSourceExcludes>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/war/work/wrapped-template</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```